# Selenium WebDriver, Apache POI, Itis reading Blank Data from Excel

Tags: apache, selenium, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

I am using Selenium with Apache POI, 
But as far as I have checked its reading blank data from excel. 
Can anybody help?

[http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/data-driven-testing-excel-poi/][1]

This is the link from where I am using Code.

http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/data-driven-testing-excel-poi/

Comment: Sometimes It is showing Nul Pointer Exception too, If that relates.

Comment: Edit your question and add your code and stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

U are probably not reading the correct cell unit or ur excel parameters are wrong -      ExcelUtils.setExcelFile(Constant.Path_TestData + Constant.File_TestData,"Sheet1");

please check it twice because i used the same code in my projects, it worked perfectly !

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways to make a check like you can add the if clause at the place you are using getcelldata function like:

```
 String sUserName = ExcelUtils.getCellData(1, 1);
if(!sUserName.isEmpty()){
//Process further
}
```

I hope this helps. :)